# Why file_get_contents without specifying a path gets nothing in NGINX

Tags: php, nginx

I'm using nginx webserver.
As I run a script like:

```
file_get_contents('colorpicker.css')
```

I get nothing on nginx. Where colorpicker.css is assumed to be in the same folder as the running script.
The same script works under apache. Cannot figure why this is happening.
Could it be related to a Nginx configuration issue ?

Comment: check the permissions on `colorpicker.css` ?

Comment: This will tell you why: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: display_errors enabled . Error reporting already set to E_ALL . Still no errors. I'm assuming that nginx do not know where the file is.

Comment: Please put your nginx/fastcgi configuration here.